# validate CKEditor with jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: php, jquery

how to validate CKeditor with jQuery validation plugin.

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#newpost").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {
                title: "required",
                cat_id: "required",
                editor1:"required"
            },
            messages: {
                title: "  Title name cannot be blank.",
                cat_id: "  Please select a category.",
                editor1: "  Post keywords cannot be blank."         
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                // do other stuff for a valid form
                $.post('new_post.php', $("#newpost").serialize(), function(data) {
                 $('#msgw').html(data);
                });             
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
include ('../db.php');

$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$editor1 = $_POST['editor1'];
$date= date("Y-m-d");
$cat_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat_id']);


$qu = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogposts(title,post,date,catid)VALUES ('".$title."','".$editor1."','".$date."','".$cat_id."')") or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

problem is it dosent even post the contain in the editor. how can i fix this problem. thank you.

Comment: Cehck the "related" column for some very similar (or identical) questions

Comment: CKEditor will change the interface of `TextArea`. You can still check the `TextArea` content. About the content passing, make sure you set the form send method and of course the name of `TextArea`.

Answer (score 0):

I have added this code below:

**CKEDITOR.instances.pdetails.updateElement();**

pdetails is the name of your textarea. And when you try to submit your form and print out the the textarea:

**$pdetails = $_POST['pdetails'];**

print $pdetails;

make sure it has a value before you have tested it.